# DataFlow SDK 2.x: PubSubIO authorization error

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

[Reading from Pubsub using Dataflow Java SDK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386425/reading-from-pubsub-using-dataflow-java-sdk-2)

I'm trying like below:

```
public class App2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create());
        pipeline
                .apply("ReadStrinsFromPubsub",
                        PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic("projects/dev/topics/trading"))
                .apply("PrintToStdout", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Void>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                        System.out.printf("Received at %s : %s\n", Instant.now(), c.element()); // debug log
                    }
                }));

        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
}
```

An error occurs caused by:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you run it on your local machine?

Comment: yes. I run this code at my local machine. how can I run this code on local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing the service account set up for your local machine to access GCP.

Please refer to [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) to set up your service account and the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable.

1) Create a service account in the GCP console;

2) Download the json key file to your local;

3) Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable to the path of the json key file.

Answer (score 1):

`gcloud auth application-default login` will enable you to use the default service account from the machine you login from.